# Stack Exchange app refuses to upload images

Tags: bug, android-app

I see the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong when trying to upload that image. Try again?

when attempting to upload an image using the Stack Exchange Android app installed from the Play Store at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin

Below is the corresponding screenshot that I had to manually upload to imgur.com in order to post:

[Imgur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLnFQ.jpg)

(Side note: I noticed that clicking on the upload image icon resulted in a link being inserted and not one that in lines the image as shown above.)

It does not seem to be related to the size of the image.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with my internet connectivity from the phone. I'm using the same app to post this question to Meta Stack Exchange.

The phone is a stock Samsung Galaxy Note 8 (the cell phone carrier is Google Fi).

Below is a screenshot of the kernel version and other Android version info from the settings on the phone:

[Phone version information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TElFA.jpg)

Application information for the Stack Exchange app is below:

App info
Version  1.0.95
Updated on  Jun 30, 2017

I just now noticed "Jun 30, 2017" above and it is now in November 2019. The phone should update the app automatically, correct? Is the phone simply too old for the app?

Comment: TL;DR: the app is dead. Nobody is there to fix any bug it has. Don't use it. (It's like using IE6, or Netscape: it might still work if you're lucky, but most things it used to have are utterly broken)

Comment: Thanks for that comment. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No, what I say doesn't answer the question because it's neither a fix for the bug, nor official rejection. SE might revive the app at some point (as slim as the chance may be), then they'll fix the bugs. I personally don't believe it will ever happen, hence posting those comments so people will not use a now-dead app. Hope it makes some sense.

Comment: The chance for development to be revived is slim in my opinion as well given the lack of activity in the last approximately two years. Hence I think the healthiest response would be for them to implement some answer to my related question at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338769/clearly-communicate-that-the-stackexchange-android-app-is-no-longer-being-develo

Comment: It's a shame. The app is/was great. More important to produce podcasts about nonsense though I suppose!