# Clearly communicate that the Stack Exchange Android App is no longer being developed

Tags: support, bug, android-app

[Stack Exchange Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) seems to have been abandoned/orphaned, because it hasn't seen any updates since June 2017, because it is November 2019 as of this writing.

Please warn other potential users that their experience with the app will be poor, because of a lack of updates. My suggestion is to update the Play Store text somewhere clearly visible with verbiage to the effect of

> This app is no longer being developed.  Please use the web browser-based interface instead.

I think this is justified given my post at *[Stack Exchange app refuses to upload images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338751/stack-exchange-app-refuses-to-upload-images)* which has at least one duplicate. Thus, I'm not the only one who was tripped up by the orphaned app, and others will post bug reports here only to find out what I have discovered as well.

Comment: Might as well remove the app from the store tbh.

Comment: Last I heard anything about them, we were planning on delisting them so people that already had them could continue using them or something like that.

Comment: It seems like in-app notification would be better than text on the Play Store, since Play Store users rarely visit the entries for apps they already have.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica Both. Both would be good.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica that would require development, something they no longer do.

Comment: @Luuklag There's a decent chance that it could be done server-side. If not, they might be willing to make a one-time exception to the nondevelopmenr policy to make that tiny change.

Comment: I think that having no android developer at all is clear enough sign. Kasra was the one and only android developer SE ever had, and he left SE over a year ago. (Not sure if willingly or not, but that's off topic here.)

Comment: Didn't you mean to use another URL at the beginning (the two URLs are identical)?

Comment: [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272122/260388)

Comment: @pandya Thanks for that sad backstory. Unfortunately, that lends weight to the theory posited in the OP.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Now fixed (good catch).

Comment: plz no in-app notification. that'd be quite irritating for those of us who decide to use it anyway, already knowing it's out of date. Currently it's the only way to receive mobile inbox notifications without relying on a mailbox, at least as far as i'm aware.

Comment: @KevinB: Web sites can send notifications now, so you should consider proposing that SE add that functionality.

Comment: @KevinB It could be a dismissable notification.