# Post scores of 1000+ do not show up correctly on the Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: bug, android-app, score

[image]

The link to the question above : [How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-a-github-forked-repository)

The votes show up as a breakdown of upvotes and downvotes. This bug seems to be applicable for both questions and answers as show in the above screenshot.

Comment: [The apps are abandoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338769/clearly-communicate-that-the-stack-exchange-android-app-is-no-longer-being-devel). No new features or bug-fixes will be forthcoming.

Comment: @yivi, Is there a way to contribute to the development of the app ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315791/make-the-mobile-apps-open-source