# Android app not showing "Feed"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, android-app-feed

The Android app is failing to load the feed. Individual site question lists work fine along with questions but the feed just shows white and on a pull to refresh it shows a red popup error saying it failed to load the feed.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Google
- Device Model: Pixel 3
- OS Version: 10 (6084386)

Comment: Bugs in the android app aren't fixed from now on. You shouldn't hope for anything.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: Also this looks very much like something on the backend that has changed, not an actual bug in the app.

Comment: Here's a post that mentions the app is no longer being developed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338769/clearly-communicate-that-the-stack-exchange-android-app-is-no-longer-being-devel

Comment: If it is something in the backend maybe a dev can poke the code. If it is the app itself there is no hope for a fix.

Comment: @JohanLiebert "from now on" ... isnt it that way for many months by now?

Comment: @ghostcat it feels like it just happened yesterday (time passes by quickly)! (hiding the fact that I used the wrong word)

Comment: There were some issues on the server end today that have since been addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what ever changed, has been changed back.

The Android app "Feed" is working again.

Comment: Apologies for this - it turns out we never had a meta.stackexchange.com post rated that highly and it crept into the feed. The code made a bad assumption about meta == child meta and did some bad tings, it has been rectified :)